# Selenium Command line server for the IEDriverServer has stopped working App Crash error

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium Python automated regression test script running on our 64bit Server on IE11, Windows Server 2008. Everytime when the test gets about half way through an error dialog appears and the test stops. The error is:

```
Command line server for the IEDriverServer has stopped working
```

The full trace is:

```
   Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: IEDriverServer.exe
  Application Version:  2.53.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    56e9abe3
  Fault Module Name:    IEDriverServer.exe
  Fault Module Version: 2.53.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   56e9abe3
  Exception Code:   40000015
  Exception Offset: 000000000001877a
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 9d60
  Additional Information 2: 9d60a3c1cb1d5911598c0ff40a26278a
  Additional Information 3: 1ee9
  Additional Information 4: 1ee9da2f8e2415daed3ffe0e1066b74e
```

Anyone know why the IEDriverServer is crashing?

On our 32bit server the tests runs ok all the way to the end.  Over 230 test cases.  But on our 64bit server the App Crash error appears half way through.

I have set the registry DWORD value:

For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

IEDriverServer.exe is also in my Path

And also i notice in Task Manager iexplore.exe it's memory usage is 2.95GB
Is this normal?  The memory seems really high.
Does Selenium need over 2.95GB of memory to run the tests in IE11?

Thanks, Riaz

Comment: Our server is hitting 100% disk usage. This may be why the Selenium test IEDriverSerer crashes half way through. I am setting this test up on another environment now. See how that goes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 32bit IEDriverServer.exe for 64Bit OS then you switch over to 64 Bit IEDriverServer.exe because there could be reason of mismatch 32bit to 64 bit combination behind crashing of IE driver, and now if using 64 bit IEdriverserver.exe and  you are having slow typing issue then to overcome this issue for  64bit exe over IE 11 browser Follow these steps:-

Internet Options -> Security -> Check "Enable Protected Mode" for all zone

Go to Advanced -> Security -> Check "Enable Enhanced Protected Mode"

this works for me. Cheers!