# Selenium IEdriverserver.exe stopped working with IE11

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver

Hello we are using selenium version 2.53.1 and IEDriverServer.exe version (2.53.1 - 32bit windows).We are executing our test cases on IE 11.We observed that after 10 to 12 test case run, IEDriverServer.exe stopped working popup comes.How to deal with this?Please help on this.

Comment: I have posted answer for same you can check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37093403/selenium-command-line-server-for-the-iedriverserver-has-stopped-working-app-cras/39286378#39286378) Cheers !